# Creating a code deciphering program

Tags: java

I have posted about this before, but I am still having some problems. I have to decode a message given by the user.

The message consists of a series of numbers and should be decoded using these substitutions:

```
1 = D
2 = W
3 = E
4 = L
5 = H
6 = O 
7 = R
```

For instance, `5344626741` is `HELLOWORLD`.

I have tried many things, and gotten close, but the output is not correct. I think there is a problem searching the string for certain characters.

Any help is greatly appreciated, here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter 10 numbers, after each number you put in, press enter. The numbers can only be from 1 - 7.");

    int numInputs = 0;
    String code = "", deciphered = "";
    int input = 0, charNumber = 7;
    //5344626741
    do{
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        input = in.nextInt();
        if(input>=8 || input<=0){
            System.out.println("Please enter a different number: ");
            input = in.nextInt();
            code+=input;
            numInputs++;
        }
        else{
        code+=input;
        numInputs++;
        }
    }while(numInputs < 10);

    System.out.println("Your code is " + code);
    for(int add = 0; add < 10; add++){
        switch(code.charAt(charNumber)){
        case '1': deciphered+="D";
        case '2': deciphered+="W";
        case '3': deciphered+="E";
        case '4': deciphered+="L";
        case '5': deciphered+="H";
        case '6': deciphered+="O";
        case '7': deciphered+="R";
        break;
        default: System.out.println("Something went wrong! Try again with numbers only 1 - 7.");
        charNumber++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The output is: "+deciphered);
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: You need a `break` for each `case`, else it falls through to next `case`.

Comment: Did you consider an array to map the number to letters?

Comment: you should also beware that when a user inputs an invalid input twice you will use it as a valid number when it should be disregarded.

Comment: perhaps display the number of inputs received and only increment that count when a valid number is entered. this way a user can see whether or not they enter a valid number by seeing the count increment when it's valid and seeing no count change when it's an invalid number entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a simple typographic error and one logic error. I believe `switch(code.charAt(charNumber))` should be changed to `switch(code.charAt(add))` and at the bottom of the second for loop you should remove `charNumber++;`

You're also missing break statements after each case statement.

Basically, in your last for loop you need to make sure you are iterating with the right indexer. Here, it looks like you've initialized `charNumber` to 7 at the beginning of your program and thus you're seeing an error when you exceed the string length.

Comment: I got the code to work. I had to add breaks to my cases and I used the charAt(add) like you suggested. Thank you very much!

Comment: @BrandonLatimer You're welcome. If you feel like this response answers your question sufficiently, don't forget to check the accept answer button!

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numInputs = 0;
    int input = 0;
    String sum = "";
    String deciphered = "";
    
    while(numInputs < 10)
    {
        int x = numInputs + 1;
        System.out.println("Enter the " + x + "º number:");
        input = in.nextInt();
        if (input >= 1 && input <= 7)
        {    
            sum += input + " ";
            numInputs++;
        } else
        {
            System.out.println("Remember the numbers range is 1 to 7, please try again.");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The encrypted code of the following numbers " + sum + "is:");
    
    // For test the exercise try with this number 5 3 4 4 6 2 6 7 4 1
    
    for (int i = 0; i < sum.length(); i++)
    {
        char a = sum.charAt(i);
        switch (a)
        {
            case '1': 
                deciphered += "D";
                break;
            case '2': 
                deciphered += "W";
                break;
            case '3': 
                deciphered += "E";
                break;
            case '4': 
                deciphered += "L";
                break;
            case '5': 
                deciphered += "H";
                break;
            case '6': 
                deciphered += "O";
                break;
            case '7': 
                deciphered += "R";
                break;
            case ' ':
                deciphered += " ";
                break;
         }
    }
    System.out.println(deciphered);
```

Comment: Hello my friend, I tried it with spaces between letters, you can modify, thanks!